# Can Valgrind's gdb server break on any violation

Tags: c, valgrind, gdbserver

I have a double free that I'm trying to hunt down. It got introduced in an edge case long ago, far enough back that I can't easily bisect to find what introduced it. So the next best way to hunt it down would be to debug it. I tried to find any documentation indicating whether Valgrind's `gdb` server could be configured to break on any violation. This would be desirable so I could understand the context of the second free. (Hopefully the invalid free is the second one).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Valgrind activates by default its embedded gdbserver. This allows a GDB to connect to it at any moment.

If you want Valgrind gdbserver to stop and wait for a connection from GDB when an error is detected, you can use the option `--vgdb-error=<number>`

By specifying `--vgdb-error=1`, valgrind will stop at the first error detected, and all the following errors.

See http://www.valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual-core-adv.html#manual-core-adv.gdbserver for more details